# Laravel 4 with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel PHP Framework with Bootstrap. I want to know how to insert a datepicker in to a form.

I already have the bootstrap-datepicker installed but do not know how I will use.

Here is the code of my form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'HomeController@postRegister')) }}
        <p>{{ Form::text('first_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'primeiro nome')) }}</p>
        <p>{{ Form::text('last_name', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'último nome')) }}</p>
        <p>{{ Form::text('email', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'email')) }}</p>
        <p>{{ Form::text('phone_number', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'o teu número de telemóvel')) }}</p>
        **<p>{{ Form::text('date_of_birth', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'a tua data de nascimento')) }}</p>**
        <p>{{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'a tua palavra-passe')) }}</p>
        <p>{{ Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'reintroduzir palavra-passe')) }}</p>
        <p>{{ Form::submit('regista-te', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}</p>
        {{ Form::close() }}
```

I need to replace this code for a datepicker:

```
<p>{{ Form::text('date_of_birth', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'a tua data de nascimento')) }}</p>
```

Like this:

As a componet:
[image]

I hope someone can help me :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap uses

```
 data-datepicker="datepicker"
```

to show the date picker. Laravel will allow you to use this is the same array as the class and placeholder.

```
<p>{{ Form::text('date_of_birth', '', array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'a tua data de nascimento','data-datepicker' => 'datepicker')) }}</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following has worked for me. Difference between @Marco's and my answer is **data-provide** instead of **data-datepicker**.

```
{{ Form::text('startingDate', null, array('class' => 'form-control input-sm','placeholder' => 'Starting Date','data-provide' => 'datepicker')) }}
```