# Using bootstrap datepicker in Laravel 4 form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, datepicker

I'm having some trouble trying to use the bootstrap date-picker (http://tinyurl.com/o7njj9n).

I tried using suggestions from these 2 threads:
[laravel using twitter bootstrap and datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609750/laravel-using-twitter-bootstrap-and-datepicker)
and [Laravel 4 with bootstrap-datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272257/laravel-4-with-bootstrap-datepicker) but not luck in solving the problem.

Currently, this is what I have for my form field:

```
{{ Form::text('date', null, array('type' => 'text', 'class' => 'form-control datepicker','placeholder' => 'Pick the date this task should be completed', 'id' => 'calendar')) }}
```

I reference the CSS and JS in my master template, as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/datepicker3.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

I have the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').datepicker({
    });

} );
</script>
```

I'm not sure what's wrong?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: The problem is that the calendar does not appear upon clicking inside the text field.

Comment: Can you also describe what the problem is or which errors you see if any?

Comment: Are there any errors in your developer tools console?

Comment: I see no errors. The calendar just doesn't show when I click on the text field.

Comment: remove `'data-datepicker' => 'datepicker'` from your input field.

Comment: Hi Edward, I've done as you suggest, but no luck. I've edited the code in my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by moving the 'date-picker.js' script dependency below the jquery dependency. A bit silly, I guess, but I'm new to web-dev :/